# How to remove a synced device in Windows Live Mesh

Tags: windows, windows-live-mesh

My computer broke a while ago and I got a new one. I've been using [Windows Live Mesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_Mesh) to sync files on the old one. Now that I have a new computer it just added a new device to my list of devices in Windows Live.

I don't need the broken computer to appear there anymore, but I can't figure out how to remove it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove devices going to [Live Devices](https://devices.live.com) and selecting the "administrate" option under each device

Answer (score 0):

It now seems to be called "Manage", and the "Stop using this service" link within that page only seems to work with IE - in Firefox clicking the Stop link does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to Control panel.
2. Click Hardware & Sound.
3. Click Device Manager (under devices and printers).
4. Expand "Imaging devices".
5. Right click printer you want to remove.
6. Click "Uninstall".

Job done.

Comment: -1 The OP doesn't want to remove a printer